# How to extract text from multiple pdf in a location with specific line and store in Excel?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdfminer, tika-python

I have 100 pdf stored in a location and I want to extract text from them and store in excel
below is pdf image
in this i want (stored in page1)

```
bid no,end date,item category,organisation name
```

[image]
[image]

needed

```
OEM Average Turnover (Last 3 Years),Years of Past Experience required,MSE Exemption for Years Of Experience
and Turnover,Startup Exemption for Years of Experience
and Turnover,Estimated Bid Value,EMD Required
```

[image]

Consignee address only)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tika](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python) is one of the Python packages that you can use to extract the data from your PDF files.

In the example below I'm using `Tika` and regular expressions to extract these five data elements:

- bid no
- end date
- item category
- organisation name
- total quantity

```
import re as regex
from tika import parser

parse_entire_pdf = parser.from_file('2022251527199.pdf', xmlContent=True)
for key, values in parse_entire_pdf.items():
    if key == 'content':
        bid_number = regex.search(r'(Bid Number:)\W(GEM\W\d{4}\W[A-Z]\W\d+)', values)
        print(bid_number.group(2))
        GEM/2022/B/1916455

        bid_end_date = regex.search(r'(Bid End Date\WTime)\W(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\W\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', values)
        print(bid_end_date.group(2))
        21-02-2022 15:00:00

        org_name = regex.search(r'(Organisation Name)\W(.*)', values)
        print(org_name.group(2))
        State Election Commission (sec), Gujarat

        item_category = regex.search(r'(Item Category)\W(.*)', values)
        print(item_category.group(2))
        Desktop Computers (Q2) , Computer Printers (Q2)
 
        total_quantity = regex.search(r'(Total Quantity)\W(\d+)', values)
        print(total_quantity.group(2))
        18
```

Here is one way to write out the extracted data to a CSV file:

```
import csv
import re as regex
from tika import parser

document_elements = []

# processing 2 documents 
documents = ['202225114747453.pdf', '2022251527199.pdf']
for doc in documents:
    parse_entire_pdf = parser.from_file(doc, xmlContent=True)
    for key, values in parse_entire_pdf.items():
        if key == 'content':
            bid_number = regex.search(r'(Bid Number:)\W(GEM\W\d{4}\W[A-Z]\W\d+)', values)

            bid_end_date = regex.search(r'(Bid End Date\WTime)\W(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\W\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', values)

            org_name = regex.search(r'(Organisation Name)\W(.*)', values)

            item_category = regex.search(r'(Item Category)\W(.*)', values)

            total_quantity = regex.search(r'(Total Quantity)\W(\d+)', values)
            
            document_elements.append([bid_number.group(2),
                                      bid_end_date.group(2), 
                                      org_name.group(2), 
                                      item_category.group(2),
                                      total_quantity.group(2)])


with open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    headerList = ['bid_number', 'bid_end_date', 'org_name', 'item_category', 'total_quantity']
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headerList)
    writer.writerows(document_elements)
```

[image]

Here is the additional code that you asked for in the comments.

```
import os
import re as regex
from tika import parser

document_elements = []

image_directory = "pdf_files"
image_directory_abspath = os.path.abspath(image_directory)
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(image_directory_abspath):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".pdf")]:
        parse_entire_pdf = parser.from_file(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), xmlContent=True)
        for key, values in parse_entire_pdf.items():
            if key == 'content':
                bid_number = regex.search(r'(Bid Number:)\W(GEM\W\d{4}\W[A-Z]\W\d+)', values)

                bid_end_date = regex.search(r'(Bid End Date\WTime)\W(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\W\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', values)

                org_name = regex.search(r'(Organisation Name)\W(.*)', values)

                item_category = regex.search(r'(Item Category)\W(.*)', values)

                total_quantity = regex.search(r'(Total Quantity)\W(\d+)', values)

                document_elements.append([bid_number.group(2),
                                          bid_end_date.group(2),
                                          org_name.group(2),
                                          item_category.group(2),
                                          total_quantity.group(2)])

with open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    headerList = ['bid_number', 'bid_end_date', 'org_name', 'item_category', 'total_quantity']
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headerList)
    writer.writerows(document_elements)
```

**SPECIAL NOTE:**  I noted that some PDFs don't have an org_name, so you will have to figure out how to handle these with either a `N/A, None, or Null`

Comment: pls tell how how to extract TOTAL Quantity as well

Comment: @AkhilJain. I have updated the answer to include the other data element.

Comment: instead of hardcoding the pdf the program should pick all the pdf present in C: directory

Comment: @AkhilJain I added the additional code, which you will need to weave into your final solution.

Comment: kindly write code in one para

Comment: @AkhilJain one para?

Comment: means pls embed  the path code with the above code

Comment: @AkhilJain I added the code as you requested and this code also outputs your CSV file.

Comment: getting error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @AkhilJain that error tells me that one of your documents is causing an issue.  Does the error message tell you, which line is causing the problem?  Do you know which document caused the error?

Comment: problem solved.

Comment: i have edited the Question want some more fields if you can help with that !!

Comment: @AkhilJain Have you tried to add the new regular expressions to the extraction code?  The base format is this -- `r'(COLUMN NAME)\W(.*)'`. For example `bid_to_ra = regex.search(r'(Bid to RA enabled)\W(.*)', values)`

Comment: could u help me the Consignee address image added in question  (last request)

Comment: @AkhilJain what is the "consignee address image"?

Comment: the last image i have added @Life

Comment: I NEED THE ADDRESS COLUMN VALUE ONLY @LIFE

Comment: there can be more than 1 Consignee/reporting officer Quantity table in the pdf

Comment: @AkhilJain extracting a single table column on multiple rows is much harder using only the `tika.parser`.  I need to do some research in the best way to accomplish this and how to incorporate this new requirement while meshing it with the current code.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex waiting !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract data from pdf tables to excel, you can use tabula https://tabula.technology/.  It's actually pretty good for this kind of thing.

The following code might help you get started:

```
pdf_folder = 'C:\\PDF extract\\pdf\\'
paths = [pdf_folder + fn for fn in os.listdir(pdf_folder) if fn.endswith('.pdf')]

for path in paths:
    listdf = tabula.read_pdf(path, encoding = 'latin1', pages = 'all', nospreadsheet = True,multiple_tables=True)
    path = path.replace('pdf', 'csv')
    df_concat = pd.concat(listdf)
    df_concat.to_csv(path, index = False)
```

sourced from:  [looping through pdf files with tabulizer in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464436/looping-through-pdf-files-with-tabulizer-in-python)