# pdf2text not compatible with Python 3.7 version

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, text, pip

I am trying to install pdf2text with Python 3.7 installed on my machine and I am getting a error

> SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(**version**)?
>   Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(**version**)?

Is there any other solution to this,I need pdf2text to extract some unstructured table from a pdf file and based on the content of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532770/extract-identify-tables-from-pdf-python) post on stackoverflow it seems pdf2text works well with unstructured tables extraction.

Comment: is there a cod you trying to execute?

Comment: No, its a library "https://pypi.org/project/pdftotext/"

Comment: i mean when did you get error? import pdf2text or pip install pdf2text or something else

Comment: pip install, using Pycharm user-interface to do the installation

Comment: probably that lib writen for python2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like library for python 2.x you can try install pdftotext:

```
pip install pdftotext
```

or you can download pdf2text wheel and configure it for python 3 like:

`print version` to `print(version)`